# find the volume of the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ outside of the cone $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ using spherical coordinates in the first octant

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I setup the triple integral as follows:
$$
\int _{\frac{\pi }{4}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\:\int _0^2\:p^2sin\phi dpd\theta d\phi \:
$$

When I evaluate this I get the answer as:
$$
\frac{2\sqrt{2}\pi }{3}
$$
The correct answer should be
$$
\frac{4\pi }{3}
$$

I think my mistake is with the bounds for the p.
$$
0<p<2 
$$
But I'm not sure what I should change it to. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the cylinder have a finite volume with bounds $0\le z\le2$? If so, note the cone is just a third of its volume.

Comment: yeah, but the class is a calculus class so I think if I solved it using that method I wouldn't get any marks.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Hint: the volume _inside_ the cone is an integral, $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_0^z\rho d\rho dzd\phi$.

Comment: Did the problem itself actually specify using *spherical coordinates*? I ask because the obvious choice here would be to use cylindrical coordinates, as J.G. shows (though their $\phi$ is your $\theta$). With spherical coordinates, the upper limit of $\rho$ will be a function of $\phi$. Also note that the limits on $\theta$ in your integral should be $0$ to $2\pi$ for the full cylinder. $0$ to $\frac \pi 2$ will only be a quarter of the cylinder.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yeah the professor gave it to us as a challenge. we solved it in class using cylindrical but she challenged us to solve it using spherical coordinates. So my upper limif of $\rho $ should be a function of $\phi $. I also forgot to include that the question was asking only for the first octant. will update the question.

Comment: Each pair of values for $\theta$ and $\phi$ determine a ray extending from the origin. $\rho = 0$ is the origin, and as $\rho$ increases the point of integration moves out along this ray. Integration with respect to $\rho$ stops when there the ray exits the cylinder. By the cylindrical symmetry of the functions, the limits on $\rho$ do not vary with $\theta$. So we can look at a two-dimensional slice with fixed $\theta$. The cylinder becomes a rectangle in that slice, with the ray extending from the origin at an angle $\phi$. The upper limit is where that ray crosses the rectangle.